# Symantec Endpoint Protection virus definition files

Tags: anti-virus, symantec, symantec-endpoint-protection

Are Symantec Endpoint Protection virus definition files protected by
"Protect Symantec security software from being tampered with or shutdown" option?

In other words I want to know if virus definition files have tamper protection in  SEP?

Answer (score 1):

OK I actually found the answer. Definitions are protected by tamper protection in SEP

Described in article: TECH103176
Article URL http://www.symantec.com/docs/TECH103176